# Load MainViewController when using 'Open In App' no matter what view is currently open

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a basic application with two views in it.  There is a mainviewcontroller that I would like loaded every time they user opens the application using 'Open In Application' with a csv file, no matter what view the application was in when the user left.

For example, if the user is in the editviewcontroller and leaves the application, finds a csv file, and selects 'Open in application' I would like it show the mainviewcontroller.  However if the user is in the editviewcontroller, leaves the application and comes back to the application without using the 'Open In Application' with a csv file I would like it to display the page that was already open (the editviewcontroller in this case).

I've found it easy enough to determine if the user selected 'Open In Application' because the openURL method from the AppDelegate gets called.  However I'm finding it extremely difficult to either determine if the editviewcontroller is already open and close it or have the application open the mainviewcontroller from here no matter what view is open, or any other way of doing this.  If someone could give me an idea of how to do this that would be great.

Thanks for the help.

Edit (Updated code with help):

```
UIViewController *currentView = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
if ([currentView.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"EditViewController"])
{
    [currentView dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: window.rootviewcontroler should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method from the `AppDelegate` you have access to `self.window.rootViewController`.

A viewController has access to `presentedViewController`.

i.e. `self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController`

So you could dismiss it if it exists.